# C# - What is the proper connection string to use for a local mdf db file that will be used on multiple computers

Tags: c#, connection-string, mdf

I'm a relatively new programmer so I apologize in advance if my question isn't exactly clear or my terminology isn't precise. I have recently been putting together Windows Form Application using Visual Studio 2015 with a small group of people. In the application I have a mdf database file that was created using Visual Studio. I'm able to connect to it no problem on my end using the connection string:

"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\Database.mdf;Integrated Security = True");

with the above being a path on my machine. But I am drawing a blank on how I would set it up so that the connection string doesn't have to be altered when someone else tries to use it on a different machine.

I've seen suggestions to use things like |DataDirectory| and things of that nature but I haven't had any luck so far.

So is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance for any help that is provided.

Comment: You need to use relative path of the .mdf file. You can put the file in some directory, let say `DataFiles` which is located at the same place from where your program is running. And in connection string you can provide relative path like `.\DataFiles\Database.mdf`. You just need to make sure that the `DataFiles` folder with `Database.mdf` is copied along with the program to the machine where you want to run program.

Comment: Try looking for alternatives provided in https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. For multi-user connection string, I suggest you to setup an SQL Server instance, then provide connection string which contains remote server address, database name & authentication schema.